# Does Android Studio have parts of the adb client built-in? How does Android Studio use adb?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I know that Android Studio requires adb, but it doesn't seem to use it except as a server. I wrote a wrapper around adb to see how it was called, and Android Studio only seems to call the following:

```
% adb version
% adb start-server
```

And then it somehow gets the list of clients on adb without calling 'adb devices' and manages to do the push and pull itself.

I ask because I'm trying to write a wrapper around the adb client that handles multiple devices, but Android Studio won't call adb for these things.

So how does Studio (v1.2.2) get the list of devices and interact with these devices if not through adb?

Comment: Presumably it uses a network socket to talk to the running server instance, same as subsequent runs of the command-line tool do.  You probably want to look through the adb source - it's in system/core in AOSP.

Comment: I don't think looking at the adb source would help since it doesn't seem to be calling adb.

And your 'presumably' may be true, but I'm trying to find verification of that - does Studio have an adb client builtin that connects to adb servers?

Comment: I didn't say it was calling it, I said it was using a network socket to talk to it.  Looking at the ADB source will show you how the ADB client/server protocol works.  If you are in Linux you can look at the android studio process's sockets and see that it is connected to ADB.

Comment: just use a sniffer/netstat/lsof/tool of your choice to see what's connecting to the adb server port